# Inject js from IhttpModule

Tags: c#, asp.net, ihttpmodule

i trying to inject js to page (to  tags) by using ihttpmodule.
but js isn't injected.

what i did:

## the page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyTempProject._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Temp</title>   
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

## the ihttpmodule:

```
public class MyExtensionModule : IHttpModule
    {
        #region IHttpModule Members

        public void Dispose()
        {

        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {

            context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);            
        }




        void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
            Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
            if (page != null)
            {
                string script = "/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js";
                if (page.Header != null)
                {
                    string scriptTag = String.Format("<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"{0}\"></script>\n", script); page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(scriptTag));
                }
                else if (!page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered(page.GetType(), script)) page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(page.GetType(), script, script);
            }


        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: well it's never gonna get added to page.Header because that doesn't exist (based on your code).  Is anything being output?  Have you stepped through the code?  Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: no, doesn't any exception..it's never add the scripttag.. so how can i to add to head tags? have any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **BeginRequest** event is way too early to hook into a page. At that point in the request cycle, IIS/ASP.NET hasn't even decided to map your request to anything. So you should probably try something like the **PostMapRequestHandler** event.

However, that's not all there is to it: at that point the page (if there is one) hasn't executed yet. That happens right between the **PreRequestHandlerExecute** and **PostRequestHandlerExecute** events. So Pre... is too early, and Post... is too late. Your best bet is to hook a page event such as **PreRenderComplete**, and there execute your injection.

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{
    context.PostMapRequestHandler += OnPostMapRequestHandler;
}

void OnPostMapRequestHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
    Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
    if (page != null)
    {
        page.PreRenderComplete += OnPreRenderComplete;
    }
}

void OnPreRenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page page = (Page) sender;
    // script injection here
}
```

**CAUTION:** Few people still use them, but **Server.Execute** and **Server.Transfer** *do not execute any pipeline events*. So such child requests can never be caught using an **IHttpModule**.

Comment: I just learnt something today. Is there any equivalent to `Server.Transfer` that does execute pipeline events?

Comment: Thanks!!! i learnt new things about that:) for right now it's worked perfectly.. i can use Response.redirect instead of Server.Transfer?

Comment: Response.Redirect causes your *browser* to initiate a *new* request, so yes, the entire pipeline is executed.