# Inject <script> tag into <head> in code behind

Tags: asp.net, global-asax, code-behind

I need to find a global way to inject a `<script>` tag into my pages directly within the `<head>` tag from the code behind.  Is there something I can do in the global.asax?  If not, all my aspx pages inherit a class I have "BasePage" that implements System.Web.UI.Page.

Basically, I need a way to push jQuery into all of my pages "before" any other scripts (in the HEAD) are referenced.

Comment: Take a look at HttpModules. Here's a [sample with someone doing][1] that with JavaScript.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239605/inject-js-from-ihttpmodule

Comment: @Chris - I am trying to add to the HEAD tag.  That doesn't seem to do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (result)
    {
        Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
        if (page is Page)
        {
            page.ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "HeadScript",
            "<script>alert('error')</script>");
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe something such as above works for you. `Application_EndRequest` is defined in `Global.asax`.

Comment: My script needs to be included as the first script within the HEAD tag.

Comment: @Brian: Then you can use `ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` to include your scripts inside of head element. More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178207.aspx

Comment: ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock seems to be putting the code in the BODY as well.

Comment: Then use `page.Header.Controls.Add(new Literal().Text = "<script></script>")`.

Comment: Durn! Try this one `page.Header.Controls.Add(new Literal("<script></script>")`

Comment: The Header property on "page" is null so I can't access the "Controls" property.  Is this a lifecycle problem?

Comment: I am sorry there is something wrong with my code, I will try to come up with something working properly.

Comment: I know i'm late, but for Page.Header to work, your head tag must be marked by "runat=server" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. It can be adapted to add to a master page too.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx